# Confirming password and checking valid email in registration form php

Tags: php, email, passwords

So I got an registration form in php. And I want to add password confirmation and check valid email, what is the best way to go about this? I checked around but nothing seems to work for me. I would like to add for both client side and server side to be sure. My  code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'Users');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); //Use MySQLi as MySQL is depreciated.

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
{
$error = false;
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
 echo "Invalid email format"; 
 $error = true
 }
}
 {

 if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['cpass']) {
   echo "Password and confirm password fields do not match!";
   $error = true;
 }

}





 //No need for functions, do it all here as otherwise you'll have to declare globals.
 if (!$error) {
    $query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM Websiteusers WHERE email = ?"); //Preparing the SQL query (We don't insert values directly into the query)
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "s", $_POST['email']); //Bind the email to the SQL query
    mysqli_stmt_execute($query); //Execute the query
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($query); //Store the results
    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($query)) //Is the number of rows 0?
    {
        //Yes
        echo "Det verkar som att du redan är registrerad";
    }

    else

    {
        //No
        $query = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers (firstname,efternamn,email,password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"); //Preparing the SQL query (We don't insert values directly into the query)
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "ssss", $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['efternamn'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']); //Bind the params to the SQL query
        mysqli_stmt_execute($query); //Execute the query
        echo "Din registrering är slutförd";
    } 
  }
 }
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="sv"> 
<head> 
<title>Registrera Dig</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head> 

<body> 

<table>
    <form method="POST" action="test.php"> 
    <img class="bild">
        <tr> <td class="ett">Namn</td><tr><td> <input class="två" type="text" name="firstname"></td> </tr></tr> 
        <tr> <td class="tre">Efternamn</td><tr><td> <input class="fyra"type="text" name="efternamn"></td></tr> </tr> 
        <tr> <td class="fem">Email</td><tr><td> <input class="sex"type="text" name="email"></td></tr></tr> 
        <tr> <td class="sju">Lösenord</td><tr><td> <input class="åtta"type="password" name="password"></td> </tr></tr> 
        <tr> <td class="nio" >Bekräfta lösenord </td> <tr><td><input class="tio" type="password" name="cpass"></td></tr> </tr>
        <tr> <td><input class="skapa" id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Skapa konto"></td> </tr> 
    </form> 
  </table>
<img src="logo.png">

</body>
```

Comment: Suggest searching this site for "php password" and "validate email php".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your validation rule this way:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  if ($_POST['pass'] !== $_POST['cpass']) {
       echo "Password and confirm password fields do not match!";
  }

  if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     echo "Invalid email format"; 
  }

  /*Other code*/
}
```

About the HTML, you can add HTML attributes like required which will deal with blank validation. Also, input type email for email would be handy.

```
<input class="två" type="text" name="firstname" required>
<input class="fyra"type="text" name="efternamn" required> 
<input class="sex" type="email" name="email" required>
<input class="åtta"type="password" name="password" required>
<input class="tio" type="password" name="cpass" required>
```

Comment: nice it worked great, you know of any way for email?

Comment: Please take a look at my edited post. I've added "required" attribute for all fields, and input type="email" for email.

Comment: could you please look through my updated code and see what the problem is, it won't register me even when I give correct email and password

Comment: There's no need to write this  if (isset($_POST['submit']))  multiple times. Just specify this once on top.

Comment: alright fixed that just one little problem is that it echoes invalid email and that password don't match, but it still register me, I updated code above

Answer (score 1):

### E-mail:

Checking an email address on validity can be done like so.

```
<?php
  $email = "com@com.com";

  if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    echo("$email is a valid email address");
  } else {
    echo("$email is not a valid email address");
  }
?>
```

However you cannot tell if the email address is real. That is why you need to send an email to the user with an activation key.

Generate a unique hasha and store that in a database table with a timestamp on insert and with a user id or email address.

The link in the email would refer to a page to check this data on validity with in a time of 30 mins? and then you know the email address is valid.

### Password:

Mostly depends on what verion of PHP you're using. If PHP 7 you're in luck cause that is really really easy.

2 functions, `password_verify()`, `password_hash()`. [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) [2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

First upon registering store the hashed password in a database column.
Now with a login, use the user submited password and compare that with the hashed password in the database.

If you're using a version of PHP < 5.5.0, I would recommend taking a look at existing login systems because a safe and secure login system is hard to develop.

### Security

It might be wise to improve your validation of user submitted data.
For example, If I were to create a username with the value of: `<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>` or include a script hosted somewhere I can steal cookies. If I have your session cookie I can login to your account.

1. Check username on min, max length.]
2. Use regex to filter for allowed chars.
3. Don't store a password in plain text.
4. Make sure the length of the data does not exceed table column lengths.
5. Always verify if `mysqli_stmt_execute($query)` ran successfully. (error logs can provide significant insight into onces system (though, you can disable error reporting)

Comment: alright thanks for the pointer, any good ones you know or where can I look?

Comment: `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` are available since PHP 5.5.0. For 5.5.0 > PHP >= 5.3.7 there is [single-file library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to add this functionality.

Comment: @Przemek I was unaware of this, thanks for the useful comment.

Comment: @Markus None from the top of my head, but a quick search I found [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) it looks solid, but rely s on `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. Use it as a base and the only thing left is to find an encryption class and password salting to safely store your passwords.